# Flask - redirecting urls to API server

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am using APIs to power my UI, which are hosted on another server. Since, I cannot do cross domain requests, I am writing a server side API wrapper that will forward all API requests to second server and return the response back.

```
@flask.route("/v1/projects/questions/*")
@flask.route("/v1/projects/answers/*")
def forward_to_api_server():
    # pseudo code below:
    json_resp = HttpUtil.request(server_base_url, url_path, headers_dict, params_dict)
    return json_resp
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: You should use the webserver (Apache, nginx, …) which is in front of your flask to do that.

Comment: @KlausD. Since its a pretty large application involving several people, currently we cannot do changes at apache level. I have access only at flask level.